# Segmentation fault with client C++ program

Tags: c++, sockets, unix

I am having some difficulty with finding out how to correct the segmentation fault.
client.cpp

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

using namespace std;

int call_socket(char *hostname, unsigned short portnum)
{
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    struct hostent *hp;
    int a;
    int s;

    if ((hp = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL)
    {
        errno = ECONNREFUSED;
        return(-1);
    }

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    memcpy((char*) &sa.sin_addr, hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
    sa.sin_family = hp->h_addrtype;
    sa.sin_port = htons((u_short)portnum);

    if ((s=socket(hp->h_addrtype, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        return(-1);
    }
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof (sa)) < 0)
    {
        close(s);
        return(-1);
    }
    return(s);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n;
    int s;
    int b;
    char username[256];
    string hostname;
    string usern;
    string terminated = "Server Terminated";
    string doesnotexist = "does not exist.";

    hostname = "localhost";
    
    char *hostn[hostname.size()+1];
    strcpy(*hostn, hostname.c_str());

    cout << "Enter a server port number: " << endl;
    cin >> s; 
    while (s <2000 || s > 65535)
    {
        cout << "Server port number must be between 2000 and 65535. Please enter the server port number again." << endl;
        cin >> s;
    }

    if ((b = call_socket(*hostn,s)) < 0)
    {
        perror("call Socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "Enter a user name: " << endl;
    cin >> usern;
    strcpy(username, usern.c_str());
    n = write(b, username, strlen(username));
    if (n < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error writing to socket" << endl;
    }

    bzero(username, 256);
    n = read(b,username,255);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error reading from socket" << endl;
    }

    if (username == terminated)
    {
        printf("%s\n",username);
    }
    else if (username == doesnotexist)
    {
        cout << "The username: " << usern << ", ";
        printf("%s\n",username);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The public key for " << usern << " is: ";
        printf("%s\n",username);
    }

    close(b);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried valgrind and got: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s), Use of uninitialised value of size 8, Invalid write of size 8. As I am unexperienced with valgrind, I don't really know how to fix it.

Comment: You are not properly handling the null terminator.

Comment: Don't be "That Guy". Give variables descriptive names. `n`, `s`, and `b` are woefully insufficient and make your job and ours more difficult than they need to be.

Comment: Lot of unnecessary copying of strings going on. For example, `n = write(b, username, strlen(username));` could be `n = write(b, usern.c_str(), usern.size());`

Comment: Why exactly do you need a nonstandard variable length array of pointers to store a hostname?

Comment: The return values of `read` and `write` are more than just "Negative is bad". They also tell you how much was written or read, and this is vital information.

Comment: `bzero(username, 256);` should get around the null termination problem mentioned above, but it's a pretty brutal way to do it, setting 256 bytes where only one needed to be set.

Comment: TCP/IP is an unstructured stream of octets. There is no correspondence between sends at one and and receives on the other.

Comment: `char *hostn[hostname.size()+1]; strcpy(*hostn, hostname.c_str());` Writes to unallocated memory pointed to by an uninitialized pointer contained in a non-standard variable-length-array.  Why do you need `hostn` at all anyway?  Just use `hostname.c_str()` and fix the const-correctnes in `call_socket`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is almost certainly here:

```
char *hostn[hostname.size()+1];
strcpy(*hostn, hostname.c_str());
```

This has several issues:

1. `hostn` is a variable-length-array, which is not a standard part of C++
2. `hostn` is an array of `char*`, not an array of `char`
3. The pointers in `hostn` are uninitialized, and thus don't point anywhere useful.
4. You pass the first element of `hostn` to `strcpy` as the destination

Since `strcpy` will attempt to dereference the pointer passed to it and that pointer is uninitialized, that means your program's behavior is undefined.

---

Note that all of this could be avoided easily.  Just get rid of `hostn` entirely.  It's not serving any purpose beyond what `hostname.c_str()` already serves.  Simply change `call_socket` to accept a `const char*` instead of a `char*`, and you can call it directly using `hostname.c_str()` (i.e. `call_socket(hostname.c_str(), s)`)